# Alfresco unable to connect to server http://mydomain:8080/alfresco

Tags: alfresco, alfresco-share

i am running alfresco on linux server i am able to access the files from back end but when running http://mydomain:8080/ it gives the following error

***Unable to connect
Firefox can’t establish a connection to the server at mydomain:8080.
    The site could be temporarily unavailable or too busy. Try again in a few moments.
    If you are unable to load any pages, check your computer’s network connection.
    If your computer or network is protected by a firewall or proxy, make sure that Firefox is permitted to access the Web.***

tomcat is running but i still cant figure out what could be the cause of the error.

Comment: i am using alfresco community 5.2.0. Please note that it has been running well but after i installed some amps files thats when i got the error

Comment: What's in the tomcat logs and the alfresco.log?

Answer (score 0):

Could you take a look to a tomcat logs?. Maybe you can find more information about the issue.
Could you check compatibility of your amps files with Alfresco version?

Regards,
clv

Answer (score 0):

First, try to hit the Alfresco webapp from the local server itself using curl, like:

```
curl -v -uadmin http://localhost:8080/alfresco
```

And see what comes back. If you get a 200 or a redirect, try Share next, like:

```
curl -v http://localhost:8080/share
```

If you get a 200 or a redirect then both web applications are working fine and this is due to a network connectivity problem between your client machine and the server or a firewall issue.

If curl cannot hit one of the web applications locally, you should inspect the logs ($TOMCAT_HOME/logs/catalina.out) to figure out why.

You can also "ps -ef|grep tomcat" to make sure Tomcat is actually running, and you can "netstat -atnp|grep 8080" to make sure Tomcat is listening on the port you think it is.

If all of the firewall and networking tests are fine and the logs have no clues, uninstall the AMPs one-by-one until it starts working again.